# getting json data into assemble templates in grunt

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I am using assemble (https://github.com/assemble/assemble) via a grunt plugin to build static pages.

I have been using grunt for a while now so understand how it all works, yet this is my first time using assemble so I looked at this for ref (http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/07/06/building-a-static-site-using-grunt-and-assemble.html). Everything seemed to be working fine.

However, I want to introduce JSON data to the mix  and have looked at the docs on the assemble site (http://assemble.io/docs/Data.html) yet after I run 'grunt assemble' it doesnt render the json data :(

My gruntfile

```
 assemble: {
        options: {
            layout: "src/responsive/layouts/default.hbs",
            data: 'src/responsive/data/**/*.json',
            flatten: true
        },
        pages: {
            files: {
                'src/': ['src/responsive/pages/*.hbs']
            }
        }
    },
```

test json:

```
{
  "name ": "This is a square widget" ,
  "modifier ": "widget-square" 
 }
```

and folder structure:

```
- data
-- index.json
- layouts
-- default.hbs
- pages
-- index.hbs
```

Within pages/index.hbs I am trying to call {{ index.name }} or simply {{ name }} (I have tried both) to no avail.

Im pulling my hair out as grunt is giving no errors (and in fact if I make json not valid grunt complains so it is reading it).

Any help much appreciated before I go crazy....

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Something else must be happening here - I just tested this out and it worked.  I would add [this helper](https://gist.github.com/kellyjandrews/2ba221d64574ba02bd34) and see what's in scope for that page. Good luck!

Comment: BTW - I'm assuming it's a typo here that the spaces are being added by SO, and not in your code? If not, that was the issue - I did have to modify that, and can add that as the answer if it's the case here.

Comment: Kelly, you are a life saver... How I missed the extra space I'll never know.

Comment: Added as answer, glad you got it working!

Comment: Adi, would you mind checking my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON here is the issue.  You had extra spaces in your `keys`.  Your JSON should be formatted as the following:

```
{
  "name": "This is a square widget",
  "modifier": "widget-square" 
}
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer. Where in the JSON is the issue? How would you fix it?

Comment: Realistically - should this be closed as being just a typo?  The extra spaces in the JSON caused the issue, the JSON in my answer if used solves the problem, but it's nothing more than additional spaces being removed.