# assemble.io cannot use data json file

Tags: json, gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I have `src/data/mydata.json` file with this content (copied from [getting json data into assemble templates in grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740072/getting-json-data-into-assemble-templates-in-grunt-argh))

```
{
  "name": "This is a square widget",
  "modifier": "widget-square"
}
```

When I try to use it in `somepage.hbs` I get nothing

```
<div class="col-md-5">

        {{mydata.name}}
</div>
```

Why?

`Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        assemble: {
            options: {
                assets: "dist/assets",
                dara: "src/data/*.json",
                layoutdir: "src/layouts/",
                flatten: true

            },
            pages: {
                options: {
                    layout: "page.hbs"
                },
                files: {
                    "dist/": ["src/*.hbs", "!src/index.hbs" ]
                }
            },
            homepage: {
                options: {
                    layout: "homepage.hbs"
                },
                files: {
                    "dist/": ["src/index.hbs" ]
                }
            }
        },

        copy: {
            assets: {
                files: [
                    { expand: true, cwd: "src/assets/", src: ["**"], dest: "dist/assets/" }
                ]
            }
        },

        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: 'src/**',
                tasks: ['assemble', 'copy'],
                options: {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-assemble' );
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['assemble', 'copy' ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a mistype in my `Gruntfile`, da**r**a instead of da**t**a. Looks like it works fine after fixing it.